# How do I locate the rabbit?

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library, object-detection

I am trying to follow the rabbit in the game winterbells. Here are some screenshots[image: rabbit][image: rabbit][image: rabbit]

Originally I thought that I could follow a color that only the rabbit had, but it seems that all the objects (i.e. the bells and dove) have the same colors. I can detect all the objects by just searching for white (see results)[image: results]

but I can't figure out how to find the rabbit. Would I have to use opencv? The only module I've used is pil to detect the colors of the pixels. It seems like an easy task but I just don't see how I can do it.

Comment: Use SimpleCV. It'll be so much easier to work with. I'd just use blob detection to find the white blobs.

Comment: I'll check out simplecv, but even with blob detection how would I differentiate between the rabbits and the bells?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The simplest way would be to just classify the shapes by area. Here's one solution with SimpleCV:

```
>>> from SimpleCV import *
>>> image = Image('image.png')
>>> binarized = image.binarize(220).invert()
>>> binarized.show()
```

[image]

Now, this is much easier to work with. You can use simple blob detection to filter out the bells and the bird:

```
>>> blobs = binarized.findBlobs()
>>> for blob in blobs:
...    blob.draw()
...    print blob
...    binarized.show()
...    raw_input()
```

After pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> 50 times and looking at the areas of the blobs, you'll notice that the bells have an area between 630 and 660. The bird has an area of 540 and the rabbit has an area of about 750.

Now, it's just a matter of filtering out the blobs you don't want:

```
>>> rabbit = next(b for b in blobs if abs(750 - b.area()) < 60)
>>> rabbit.draw()
>>> binarized.show()
>>> rabbit
    SimpleCV.Features.Blob.Blob object at (381, 445) with area 754
```

[image]

There's your rabbit.

So to wrap things up, your script would look like:

```
from SimpleCV import *

image = Image('image.png')
binarized = image.binarize(220).invert()
blobs = binarized.findBlobs()
rabbit = next(b for b in blobs if abs(750 - b.area()) < 60)

print rabbit.coordinates()
```

Answer (score 0):

i think, you can try to use svm to classify rabbit and bell. First, you can detect all objects, and then classify them with svm.